# Cómo pasar de int a cadena de caracteres en C

Tags: c

estoy practicando en C, haciendo una encuesta, y quiero saber cómo puedo hacer que en la función de Sexo cuando elige 1, guarde la respuesta como Masculino, 2 como Femenino y 3 como si no indicó.

Si alguien pudiera decirme bien cómo funciona estaría muy agradecido, aquí les dejo mi código para que se entienda un poco mejor lo que estoy tratando de hacer, estoy trabajando con estructura y función.

Me pasa que en la salida me aparece esto:

Nombre|Edad|Sexo|Semestre|

Vanessa|18||1| ... Osea no me quiere decir el Sexo de la que le voy a hacer la encuesta.

```
int n; //variable que pregunta cuantas veces va a repetirse la encuesta
int i; //ciclo


int main(){
printf("Cuantas personas vas a encuestar?: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

menu();
}

struct Encuestados{

    char Nombre[30];
    int Edad;
    char Sexo[10];
    int Telefono;
    int Zona;
    int Semestre;
    int Materias;
}nEncuestados[];

char nSexo(char *Sexo){ 
    int casos;
    nEncuestados[n];
    printf("Ingresa tu sexo (1)Masculino (2)Femenino (3)Prefiero no indicar \nElige: ", i+1);
    scanf("%s", &casos);
    switch(casos){
        case 1:
            *Sexo = 'Masculino';
            break;
        case 2:
            *Sexo = 'Femenino';
            break;
        case 3: 
            *Sexo = 'N/A';
            break;      
    }
    return Sexo;
        
    }


void menu(){
nEncuestados[n];


for(i = 0; i<n; ++i){

   printf("Ingresa tu nombre: ", i+1);
   scanf("%s", &nEncuestados[i].Nombre);
   printf("Ingresa tu edad: ", i+1);
   scanf("%d", &nEncuestados[i].Edad);
   nSexo(&nEncuestados[i].Sexo);
   printf("En cual semestre estas?: ", i+1);
   scanf("%d", &nEncuestados[i].Semestre);
}
printf("Nombre|Edad|Sexo|Semestre|\n");
for (i = 0; i<n; ++i){

    printf("%s|%d|%s|%d|\n",nEncuestados[i].Nombre,nEncuestados[i].Edad,nEncuestados[i].Sexo,nEncuestados[i].Semestre, i+1);
    

}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando ***sprinf*** para recoger las cadena en la variable y guardarla de forma permanente:

```
char nSexo(char *cSexo){ 
    int casos;
    char *Sexo="Otros";//valor por defecto
    
    printf("Ingresa tu sexo (1)Masculino (2)Femenino (3)Prefiero no indicar \nElige: ");
    //Nota que Aqui leemos un entero
    scanf("%d", &casos);
    switch(casos){
        case 1:
            Sexo = "Masculino";
            
            break;
        case 2:
            Sexo = "Femenino";
            break;
        case 3: 
            Sexo = "N/A";
            break;      
    }
    //Copiamos las variables de cadena
    sprintf(cSexo,"%s",Sexo);
    return *Sexo;
       


}
```

Nota que las variables declaradas dentro de funciones no permanecen una vez terminada la ejecución de la función